# Order now and receive before xxx date (3 days in advance)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I'm creating a new online store and the client has asked for the following, basically a piece of text that says:

Standard delivery:
Order now and receive before xxx date (this should be 3 days ahead of the date)

Next day delivery:
Order now and receive before xxx date (this should be the following day)

Can anyone point me in the right direction of a script to achieve such?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just a tip (as an ecommerce platform developer), do not say "receive before tomorrow".  That means today, and someone *will* pull you (or your customer) up about it.  Instead, say something like "receive by tomorrow"

Answer (score 2):

```
$normal=date("d.m.Y",strtotime("+3 days"));
$express=date("d.m.Y",strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Please remember to set the default timezone.

Answer (score 0):

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Tg4RY/)

```
function pad(str) {
  return ("00"+str).slice(-2);
}
function formatDate(d) {
  return ""+pad(d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+
            pad(d.getDate())+" "+
            d.getFullYear();
}
$(function() {
  var now = new Date(<?php echo time(); ?>*1000);
  now.setDate(now.getDate()+1);
  $("#nextday").text(formatDate(now));
  now.setDate(now.getDate()+2);
  $("#threedays").text(formatDate(now));
});
```

Comment: I know it was confusing that he put the PHP + JS tag, but I think a solution on serverside might be the better approach, since it also works for ppl who got JS disabled. Your function also uses PHP any way.

Comment: However the client may be in a different timezone than the server, hence the client side script

Comment: But you take the server time as input, not the user time...? Where you transform the server to client?